# Decrement operation in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword, decrement

So I've just started an IT course and as part of it we're learning to code in Java; I have an assignment for next week, and while I have it figured out, I just have a question as to why it works :P

The objective was to write a piece of code that reads a number, decrements it, turns it negative and then outputs it.

This is what I had originally:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  // imports the Scanner utility to Java

  public class Question3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // defines the scanner variable and sets it to recognize inputs from the user

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    //prompts captures a number form the screen

    int a = s.nextInt();
    // defines an integer variable('a') as to be  set by input from the scanner

    --a;
    // decrement calculation( by 1)
    -a;     
    //inverts the value of a 

    System.out.println("Your number is: " + a );
    // outputs a line of text and the value of a
```

However, Eclipse(the IDE I'm using) wouldn't recognise the unary minus operator ( '-'), so it didn't work. I got it working by tweaking it to be written as follows:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
// imports the Scanner utility to Java

 public class Question3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // defines the scanner variable and sets it to recognize inputs from the user

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    //prompts captures a number form the screen

   int a = s.nextInt();
    // defines an integer variable('a') as to be  set by input from the scanner

    --a;
    // decrement calculation( by 1)

    System.out.println("Your number is: " + (-a) );
    // outputs a line of text and the inverse of the variable 'a'
```

My question here is, why would the unary minus work in the second instance but not the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--a
```

is similar to

```
a = a - 1;
```

which means at first it calculates value of `a-1` and then with `a = ...` it **assigns that value back to `a`.**

But in case of `-a` you are just calculating negative value, but it doesn't doesn't reassign it back to `a`. So since you are *not doing anything with that calculated value* it will be lost so compiler informs you that your code doesn't do what you may think it does.

Try explicitly assign that result back to `a` with

```
a = -a;
```

After this instruction `a` will hold new value which you can use anywhere.

---

This problem disappears when you are using

```
System.out.println("Your number is: " + (-a) );
```

since now compiler sees that calculated value `-a` is being used (as part of value passed to `println` method).

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't assign the result of the unary minus. The pre-decrement includes an assignment.

```
 a = -a; // <-- like this.
```

In the second use (printing), you are using the value in the print routine (and not updating `a`).

Answer (score 0):

As Elliott Frisch explained, you have to use the negation operator (`-`) to reassign the value back to the original variable before you can access it.

But why does the decrement operator (`--`) not require you to do this? It's because `a--` is more or less [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `a = a - 1`. It's just quicker to write, and it's common enough that everyone knows what it means.

Answer (score 0):

```
-   Unary minus operator; negates an expression
```

In your case

```
 -a;
```

That's an statement.

```
"Your number is: " + (-a)
```

That's an expression.